# In my code mousemove property is not working and changing the input-type range. Can explain why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label for="spacing">Spacing:</label>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="200" name="spacing" data-sizing="px" value="10">
</div>

<script>
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');

  function handleUpdate() {
    console.log(this.value);    
  }

  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
  inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUpdate));
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include any errors and the desired output.

Comment: You should try to explain your use case better and format the question to make it readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valueAsNumber this is the key.

```
  <div class="controls">
    <label for="spacing">Spacing:</label>
    <input type="range" id="someid" min="10" max="200" name="spacing" data-sizing="px" value="10">
  </div>
  
  <script>
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');
  
 
    inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        console.log(e.screenX); 
        e.target.valueAsNumber=e.screenX; 
    }));
    inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e)
    {
        console.log(e.screenX); 
        e.target.valueAsNumber=e.screenX; 
    }));
  </script>
```